# Cannot reference Project Parameter across BIML Files

Tags: ssis, biml

I have two biml files:

- BimlScript.biml - defines project parameters
- BimlScript1.biml - tries to use this in an expression.

BimlScript.biml:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Projects>
        <PackageProject Name="Test">
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Name="Foo" DataType="String">bar</Parameter>
            </Parameters>
        </PackageProject>
    </Projects>
    <Packages>
        <#@ include file="BimlScript1.biml"#>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

BimlScript1.biml:

```
<Package Name="MyPackage">
    <Variables>
        <Variable Name="TestVariable" DataType="String" EvaluateAsExpression="true">
           @[$Project::Foo]
        </Variable>
    </Variables>
</Package>
```

However, when I try to generate packages I get the following error:

> Variable @[$Project::Foo] was not found

Is it possible to reference Project parameters across files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you need to have a Packages collection within the [Projects collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726923/181965) for the included package to know it's part of a project deployment model.

```
<Projects>
    <PackageProject Name="Test">
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter Name="Foo" DataType="String">bar</Parameter>
        </Parameters>
        <Packages>
            <Package PackageName="MyPackage" />
        </Packages>
    </PackageProject>
</Projects>
```

Comment: Thanks, Bill!  That did it!